# telegram bot payment BOT_PRECHECKOUT_TIMEOUT

Tags: bots, telegram-bot, telegram-api

When paying in the bot (via payments Sberbank test and Yukassa test (didn't try other acquirers)), the bot responds to update with pre_checkout_query using answerPreCheckoutQuery and receives the response {"ok":true,"result":true}.

But the "BOT_PRECHECKOUT_TIMEOUT" error appears in the payment window. The error occurs on different accounts and different acquirers. The error occurs even if you perform the bot's actions manually.

Is that a problem on my side?

[getting pre_checkout_query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KmNHR.png)

[answerPreCheckoutQuery](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cL8jY.png)

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NJn1m.png)